# splashscreeen not working in netbeans IDE for java?

Tags: java, manifest, splash-screen

[slash screen tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RupCAYnuSus)

By following the above tutorial i did the following things

- step1: created a new project named SplashScreenTest
- step2: include the gif file named `laoding.gif` in the project
- step3: added a new JFrameForm to project with the name `StartGUI.java`
- step4: rightclick the form->properties->code->form size
  policy->generate resize code
        generate position ->untick
        generate size ->untick
        generate center ->tick
- step5: replaces "Nimbus" with "Windows" inside
- step6: right click SplashScreenTest->properties->VMoptions
  -splash:src/AppPackage/loading.gif
- step7 : open Manifest.mf write "SplashScreen-Image:
  AppPackage/loading.gif"
- step8: set main class to AppPackage.StartGUI

Now as soon as i hit the clean and build button it returns an error 
**"existing manifest file is invalid"**

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?Maybe this question too basic, but i did't find any suitable solution.Please Help me out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm kind of weirded out by the hoops you are jumping through, Netbeans actually provides support for the splash-screen via the Project's Properties

Right click the project node...

[image]

Select the "Application" properties...

[image]

Browse for the splash screen image to be used...Netbeans will automatically included within the compiled jar file...

Clean and build your project...

Comment: tried that in the first place but doesn't work either!

Comment: First of all, it works fine for me, second of all, it won't always work if you run the project from the IDE, third of all, it will work if your run the Jar from the command line...